# Which coroutine library for this matching algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, coroutine, boost-coroutine

I would like to know which coroutine library is suited to implement the following algorithm, which is a simplified model of the problem of *commutative pattern maching* of *symbolic expressions* (to be solved in a C++ open source *computer algebra system*). In general, is it right to assume stackful coroutines are needed? Are there C++ alternatives outside of coroutines?

Given two trees (or DAGs) of arbitrary length containing three types of nodes, black/red with an arbitrary number of children; black nodes have their children in fixed order, in contrast the red nodes' children order does not matter; and leaves. The algorithm to find if both trees match gets greatly complicated by the commutative nature of red nodes and by the fact that **there is no canonical order so you cannot simply sort all children of a node**. Example:

```
Source                     Pattern

red1--->leaf1, leaf2       Red1--->Leaf1, Leaf2
|                          |
red2--->leaf1, leaf2       Red2--->Leaf2, Leaf1
```

The standard (noncommutative) case is easily implemented using a class hierarchy and recursive call of a virtual member function `match()` that matches the node itself and then each of the children. Here, `leaf1` and `Leaf2` are found different, the recursive call returns `False`. If the reds are commutative however then at a red node the algorithm 1. needs to go through all permutations of its nodes, and 2., if a call to a red `match()` succeeds the permutation loop needs to be suspended because it might happen that the caller fails and a different match is needed. It does not suffice to store the state in the caller because the callee itself might have itself called `match()` and that needs to be restarted too, else a possible solution is missed.

In a functional language, `yield` in a recursive call would do the trick. The matchpy package has a Python implementation, for example. This seems like a coroutine task but which library would you use? Is `boost::coroutine` the only one suited for this? Will C++20 bring us this functionality? Can clang do this already?

Comment: Why do you need coroutines? Why not just a Functor that keeps the current state saved and just return what you would `yield` in python?

Comment: I didn't try. Can functors always replace an implementation using couroutines?

Comment: @rwst you can implement coroutines with stateful function objects (C++ nomenclature uses "Functor" for that, not the category theory thing), so vacuously yes

Comment: @rwst I might be missing something but as far as I'm concerned functors and coroutines are mostly syntactic sugar for more terse and expressive code (especially in the single threaded case). But in the end they can all be emulated with functions taking a context struct in C. That isn't to say they're useless, they can save you a bunch of boilerplate code.

Comment: Iirc recent Visual Studios have experimental coro support as a language extension